# TypeError: web3.eth.getTransactionCount(...).then is not a function

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I'm using web3 version '^0.20.6' in my node application and did following for connecting to web3 but still getting the error while calling the method getTransactionCount.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(INFURA_ADDRESS));

// Got error while calling the below function
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address).then(txCount => { });
```

> Error : TypeError: web3.eth.getTransactionCount(...).then is not a
>   function

Answer (score 5):

web3 0.20.x is not using Promises, you need to provide a callback.

```
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address, function(error, txCount) {
   // your code
});
```

[ref](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransactioncount)